# Requesting RLMObjects with the ClassName with Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm developing an app that need to synchronize from JSON files. Those files are plist created after calling an endpoint service.

So each file is named with the ClassName and contains all the objects of this type. So what I'm trying to do is to open each files and save/update/delete all those objects in my realm db.

My ugly solution for the moment is to iterate the realm schema and use a switch to match the entity classname :

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
var schema = realm.schema.objectSchema as [RLMObjectSchema]
for clazz in schema {
    switch(clazz.className){
    case Class1.className():
        var sortedArray = Class1.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingProperty("updatedAt", ascending: false)
        if(sortedArray.count>0){
            date = sortedArray.firstObject().valueForKey("updatedAt") as Int
        }
        break
    case Class2.className():
        var sortedArray = Class2.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingProperty("updatedAt", ascending: false)
        if(sortedArray.count>0){
            date = sortedArray.firstObject().valueForKey("updatedAt") as Int
        }
    break
    }
}
```

This code is to get the last updated date for an entity kind for sync purpose, but I need it for other stuffs, so this works for a few Classes but I got 40 Classes...

So I will like to know, if there is a way to request the Realm DB with just the classname? Something from the RLMRealm (ex: `RLMRealm.defaultRealm().allObjectsWithClassName("Class1")`) or creating a RLMObject with className to have access to request functions.

Answer (score 1):

There's a private, unsupported method on `RLMRealm` (declared in `RLMRealm_Dynamic.h` that you can use --
`- (RLMResults *)allObjects:(NSString *)className;`. I must warn you, however, that this method is private and currently unsupported.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't access it from swift code. Furthermore if it's unsupported, I will be stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the undocumented function dynamicObjects from the Realm class.

For example:

```
let realm = try? Realm()
let dogs = realm.objects(Dog.self)
```

Becomes:

```
 let realm = try? Realm()
 let dogs = realm.dynamicObjects("Dog")
```

They put a caveat in the source code:

> This method is useful only in specialized circumstances, for example,
>   when building components that integrate with Realm. If you are simply
>   building an app on Realm, it is recommended to use the typed method
>   `objects(type:)`.
>
> > Returns all objects for a given class name in the Realm.
> >
> > - parameter typeName: The class name of the objects to be returned.
> > - returns: All objects for the given class name as dynamic objects
> >        :nodoc:

Took me forever to figure this out as well.  Not sure why they chose not to expose this method in the documentation.